# Sealing Pet Odor on Balcony Floor

Tags: flooring, patio

We recently purchased a condo that used to be a rental unit and balcony reeks of pet urine. I cannot completely tell the type of material used for the flooring but  it looks like it’s epoxy sand or small pebble that has been paved over the plywood.

To hide or mask the smell, I was thinking about going over it with Kilz primer and then installing tiling over it. However, I wasn’t sure if primer could be used over this type of surface.

Would this proposed idea work for hiding the smell or would I run into issues with the primer adhering to this surface?

[image]

Comment: Before (or instead of) "sealing" it, hit with vinegar as a commonly effective method of neutralizing the smell.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience there is no product that either removes or seals in pet (or other) urine.  the only solution that I've found is to remove ALL the contaminated materials and replace them.

Comment: Concur - why would you want to seal it in?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds gross, but you can do some incredible cleaning using hot water and a wet/dry vac. In a two-person team, have one person slosh on hot water and scrub with a mop or brush, have the second person follow immediately behind with a wet/dry 'shopvac' using a wide squeegee nozzle, like this:

https://www.homedepot.com/p/RIDGID-2-1-2-in-Wet-Nozzle-Squeegee-Accessory-for-RIDGID-Wet-Dry-Vacs-VT2510/100046467

Almost all of the liquid is picked up. It's a lot like how a steam cleaner works for carpets. You can clean floors and surfaces that aren't normally suppose to be wet this way, including untreated wood.

You can use vinegar or whatever cleaner you wish with the hot water. Good luck!